# Chrome failed to start (chromedriver, selenium, telepot issues)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, telegram

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTWW4.png)

I trying run telegram script bot but I can't open chromedriver
Script is running fine in my windows machine, but in ubuntu i have this issues

Message:

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux
3.10.0-327.36.3.el7
```

Please help me
I don't know what I do more :{

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace in text format

Answer (score 0):

your chrome driver seems to be old , the latest version is 2.38,
 try to upgrade and check

Comment: how i can to do it bro?

Comment: i check and my chromedriver is 2.38 version

Comment: check your chrome driver whether it is for linux or windows